# Unwritten script is being added to html page that is generated from struts2 jsp

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

I am writing a jsp using struts2. After the page is opened in browser and when i click the 'view page source' I am getting the html code in which I am seeing some script which I have not written in struts2 jsp.

My struts2 jsp is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>       
<div id="form_container" align="center">

    <s:if test="hasActionErrors()" >                        <!--  Print error messages if any -->
        <div class="errorMessages" >
            <s:actionerror/>
        </div>
    </s:if>

            <s:if test="hasActionMessages()" >                      <!--  Print action messages if any -->
        <div class="successMessages" >
            <s:actionmessage/>
        </div>
    </s:if>

    <s:form action="registerOphthalmologist" method="post" validate="true">  

        <s:hidden       key="role"          label="role"    value="O"       />
        <s:textfield    key="username"      label="Choose UserName" required="true"/>
        <s:password     key="password"      label="Choose Password" required="true"/>

        <s:textfield    key="givenName"     label="Name"    required="true"/>
        <s:textfield    key="surname"       label="Surname" required="true"/>
        <s:textfield    key="age"           label="Age"     required="true"     value=""/>
        <s:select       key="gender"        label="Gender"  
                        list="#{'M':'Male','F':'Female'}" 
                        required="true"/>

        <s:textfield    key="contactNumber"     name="contactNumber"    label="Contact Number"  required="true"/>
        <s:textfield    key="email"             name="email"            label="email"           required="true"/>
        <s:textfield    key="city"              name="city"             label="City"            required="true"/>
        <s:textfield    key="district"          name="district"         label="District"        required="true"/>
        <s:textfield    key="state"             name="state"            label="State"           required="true"/>
        <s:textfield    key="country"           name="country"          label="country"         required="true"/>
        <s:textfield    key="postalCode"        name="postalCode"       label="Postal Code"     required="true"/>

        <s:textfield    key="degree"            label="Qualification"           required="true"/>
        <s:textfield    key="university"        label="University"              required="true"     value=""/>
        <s:textfield    key="hospitalName"      label="Hospital Name"           required="true"/>
        <s:textfield    key="experience"        label="Years of Experience"     required="true"     value=""/>

        <s:checkbox     key="checkMe"       fieldValue="true"       label="Agree to terms & Conditions"/>
        <s:submit       value="Register"    align="center"/>

    </s:form>
</div>  
<div class="footer">
    <p align="center">Designed and maintained by SSSIHL</p>
</div>
```

In the Html code the following code is being added.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Sairam/struts/xhtml/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm_registerOphthalmologist() {
    form = document.getElementById("registerOphthalmologist");
    clearErrorMessages(form);
    clearErrorLabels(form);

    var errors = false;

    return !errors;
}
```

I don't know why and how it is being added. Can any one tell what is happening?

Comment: Because you said so - `<s:form ... validate="true">`. :)

Comment: Can I change the contents of the script, so that I can display the error messages in my html?

Comment: Do you want to use js validation?

Comment: I want to use xml validation. That's why I gave validation="true"

Comment: Just remove `validation` attribute from form and use xml validation.

Comment: Thank you. Now the script is not being generated, but I am not able to print the 'actionerrors' in the jsp. What may the problem?

Comment: That's another story. Ask a new question and add relative code/configuration to it.